# Save filter based on user inputs to Data.Tables

Tags: r, shiny

I want to save user created filters from Data.Tables for later use. Particularly, I would like to determine what sorting and searches were done. If I am reading the Shiny code on GitHub correctly the user inputs to Data.Tables are used to generate a JSON file in function dataTablesJSON (utils.R). What would be the best way to access these parameters from inside a Shiny app? I tried a number of things but no luck sofar. Latest attempt below:

```
output$showSession <- renderPrint({
  murl <- session$registerDataObj(
    name = "MyTest",
    data = getdata(), # a function in my app that gets the 'active' dataset
    filter = function(data, req) {
      params <- URLdecode(rawToChar(req$rook.input$read()))
      q <- parseQueryString(params, nested = TRUE)
    }
  )
  print(murl)
})

# output from function above (not affected by inputs to Data.Tables)
[1] "session/1905f776d40a0b94a439ec3121796a9c/dataobj/MyTest?w="

# First few lines from function dataTablesJSON that gets the inputs I want 
dataTablesJSON <- function(data, req) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  # DataTables requests were sent via POST
  params <- URLdecode(rawToChar(req$rook.input$read()))
  q <- parseQueryString(params, nested = TRUE)
  .....
```

Comment: For now, the answer is no, you do not have access to any query parameters for DataTables. They were passed via a POST request, to which you do not have access. I'm working on a new R package for DataTables (I just started it this week), and perhaps you might have some luck there once it is published.